# Encryption and Decryption with a String key - JAVA

Tags: java, encryption

I want to write one way to encrypt some data with a String key which is the best approach?

Encode and decode A string with Key. Suppose you have a string `"ABCD"` and a key `"BC"` then the output should be `"BDDF"`.
Can some please guide me with this question?

Comment: Lay out the rules for your "encryption" algorithm, then write code to implement it. We don't know the rules, and we won't do it for you. But if you're really interested ina ctual cryptography, then don't try to design your own crypto algorithm.

Comment: What do you mean by "write one way to encrypt" are you talking about encrypting the data or signing the data?

Comment: how should we know what to do to encrypt your string? can you at least some code, something you've done so far, and tell us the problems you're having? We are **not** here to think / code for you

Comment: @randomUser56789 he could also mean `hashing` when he only wants one way to encrypt it

Comment: 5 downvote, no flag on the question. People, remember that you can vote to close a question that is not correctly asked.

Comment: indeed, the guy seems to be complete newbie and lost, he may need more guidance than downvoting. I believe people are downvoting as there is no effort shown to solve the problem by himself.

Answer (score 2):

Depends what level of security do you want

what you have described is a simple polyalphabetic substitution cipher and provides very little actual security (though it is a nice learning example, history lesson and good excercise trying to learn how to break it).

In that case you may have a finite group (an array) of characters and work with remainderless addition. Simple and working.

if you want to encrypt something more serious way, you may look for serious cryptography (in your case you need as well a pbkdf - password based key derivation function).

I have written a small [tutorial](https://gusto77.wordpress.com/2017/10/30/encryption-reference-project/) you may have a look at